# C# ref Polymorphism workaround

Tags: c#

I've made a function in C#:

```
private void customShow(Form someForm, Type formType) {
    if (someForm == null || someForm.IsDisposed) someForm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(formType);
    someForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen; 
    someForm.MdiParent = this;
    someForm.Show();
    someForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

And then I wanted to do this:

```
private void mnuKategori_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    customShow(frmKategori, typeof(Master.FrmKategori));
    frmKategori.isCRUD = true;
}
```

It failed on the method's second line because the variable frmKategori is still null after the method execution. If I make the "someForm" argument into reference, it also fails because it seems C# doesn't support polymorphism with "ref" and "out" keyword. Does anybody have a suggestion on this?
Thanks in advance for the reply.

Comment: Uh, where is `ref/out` in the code posted? Please show code that *exhibits* the problems talked about along with the *exact* error message/symptoms.

Comment: If using ref, it would be:
private void customShow(ref Form someForm, Type formType) {...}
and
customShow(ref frmKategori, typeof(Master.FrmKategori));
VS marked the function call saying that it has some invalid arguments.
Without using ref, the line:
customShow(frmKategori, typeof(Master.FrmKategori));
returned a NullReferenceException.
Anyway... Thanks to Marksl for his answer. It works awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generics perhaps?

```
private void customShow<T>(ref T someForm) where T : Form, new()
{
    if (someForm == null || someForm.IsDisposed) someForm = new T();
    someForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen; 
    someForm.MdiParent = this;
    someForm.Show();
    someForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

And then I wanted to do this:

```
private void mnuKategori_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    customShow(ref frmKategori);
    frmKategori.isCRUD = true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry that I took so long to reply. Worked like a charm. Thanks Marksl. That's exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know about "Generics". I will learn about it. Thanks a bunch mate.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply have customShow return a new instance of Form, rather than fill in a ref/out parameter? There's really no reason to have a single out param with a void function.

Incidentally, I would also replace `customShow` with `buildCustomForm`, and save the actual `Show()` method for the very end. It can be confusing otherwise.

Comment: Because if the returned object is a Form, I would need further type-casting to the object. I haven't tried this though. And I'm sorry, but I don't understand the "buildCustomForm" you suggested. The solution suggested by Marksl works well, so I shall use that for now.

Comment: If your calling function has a reference to a `Form` object, you'll need to cast it to a specific Form (one that suppports that `isCRUD` property) anyway. There's no difference between passing it by ref or returning it from the method call.